# Azure public endpoint SSL termination

Tags: ssl, virtualization, load-balancing, azure, cloud

In Azure, is there any way to set up an HTTPS endpoint directly on the public VIP, as opposed to joining each VM to a load balanced set, so that I can associate this endpoint with the SSL certificate and forward decrypted traffic to the VM's?

I know AWS allows you to install a certificate directly on the elastic load balancer and configure SSL termination, but I haven't found any guide for this in Azure.

Comment: I'd like to see the answer to this as well. Currently I don't think you can however.

Comment: Unfortunately I've only found instructions for doing it using a web worker role. In case that helps anyone: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2990804?wa=wsignin1.0

Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468911/azure-app-using-custom-domain-with-ssl-certificate

Comment: Try Azure Traffic Manager - see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934048/https-ssl-certificate-in-azure-vm-endpoints/33018797#33018797

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Application Gateway is available as of June 25, 2015.

> Azure Application Gateway helps you build highly scalable and highly
>   available applications by providing application-level (HTTP/HTTPS)
>   load balancing and delivery control. It also offers SSL offload
>   capabilities and allows the design of custom experiences based on
>   cookie affinity.
>
> For more information, please visit the [Application Gateway
>   page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to terminate SSL at the Azure endpoint directly, unfortunately. Your options are either to terminate at the VM, or use a different load balancer such as [Kemp VLM](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/kemptech/vlm-azure-basic-byol/).